# Testing Android Studio app on iPhone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, android-studio

I would like to develop Android app with Android Studio, but the only device I have for now is an iPhone (5 and 6).

Is there a way to have a live-preview of an app on iOS? For installing Android OS on iPhone I've seen solutions like iDroid, but they seem to be not supported and not exactly working in this kind of way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have a live-preview of an app on iOS?

No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to run your android app on iOS. But what you can do to test it is use the Android Virtual Emulator. It is built an to android studio. This will run an instance of Android on whatever computer you are programming with. You will be able to test your app easily on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac and an iPhone 7, you can install a hack called [Project Sandcastle](https://projectsandcastle.org). It is still in beta, and probably won't be updated ever. It doesn't support GPU, and supports only iPhone 7. The device heats as hell. I do not recommend installing this hack, just buy a cheap android device in store.